# video.js how to speed up video?

Tags: flash, html5-video, video.js

I want to use video.js to speed up videos of lectures so that I can watch it faster. This mean I have to understand the content of the lecture while the video is running at say 2x or even 2.5x speed. I am ok with chipmunk pitch, is there a way to do this in video.js?

Answer (score 1):

**data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 ,2.5, 3] }'**

Copy this in your video tag. I have used it in latest video.js version(4.6.4).

By this way, you can easily change the speeds according to your needs.